# Error while installing informatica 10.1.0 on windows 10 Pro 64-bit

Tags: informatica

I have downloaded files from https://edelivery.oracle.com/. Extracted files and
double clicked on E:\dac_win_11g_infa_win_64bit_101\Server\install.exe.
I am getting following error.

**Error:**

```
"This application has unexpectedly quit invocation of this Java application has caused an InvoationtargetException.This application will now exit(LAX)"
```

**Error Details:**

```
Flexeraax2$aaa: Windows DLL failed to load
at Flexeraax2.af(Unknown Source)
at Flexeraax2.aa(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.init(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.LifeCycleManager.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.ia.installer.Main.main(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.launch(Unknown Source)
at com.zerog.lax.LAX.main(Unknown Source)
```

**My system details:**

> Operating system: Windows 10 Pro 64-bit
>
> Ram: 16 GB
>
> Java version: Java 7 64-bit (Also tried with Java 8)

Is there any other prerequisite for informatica 10.1.0?

Is it compatible with Windows 10 Pro 64-bit?

Please give me any solution or suggestion.

Comment: Informatica 10 is available now on edelivery? There were some compatibility issues for previous versions of Informatica with Windows 10. But not sure about  Informatica 10.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt whether you are running the install.exe from the right folder. For Windows 10 use the  zip folder 1010_Client_Installer_windows10_em-64t.zip .
It will work

Answer (score 0):

`install.exe LAX_VM "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\java.exe"`

Where install.exe is the server installation file in the folder where you have stored.

Execute the above command to install it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Installer has to be executed with below command, and make sure you use java version 1.7 or below that.

```
install.exe LAX_VM "c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe"
```

https://knowledge.informatica.com/s/article/514576?language=en_US

Answer (score 0):

None of the solution worked for me. I tried n number of other solutions and tricks too as I was having similar error from an IBM's product's installation.

This is what I did and it worked perfectly fine:

**Step 1:** Run command prompt in Administrator Mode.

**Step 2:** Issue these two commands:

```
C:\Windows\system32>SET JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS="-Dos.name=Windows 10"

C:\Windows\system32>fully_qualified_path_to_your_exefile.exe
```

Got to know about it from [this link](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-content-manager-enterprise-edition-version-8700000-installation-failed-windows-server-2022).